When is a convert's birthday?
Birthdays are relevant in various halachic contexts.

The Ben Ish Chai says one should have a seuda and do learning on one's birthday (Re'eh 17).
One's age is determined by one's birthday, so calculating when one is 25 (Chazal say one should marry before 25 - Beit Shmuel 1:5; full footnote to Peninei Halacha Simchat Habayit U'Virchato 5:9:5), or calculating when one is 20 (the age when one can get the punishment of Karet) etc is relevant.
It can come up in a case of an oath, if someone swears to do something by the time they are 30, for example.

So, it seems that halacha does care about when someone's birthday is, even if "birthdays" are not a big deal in Judaism as a whole.
So my question is, when is a converts birthday?
